# Eclipse Mars will not open (Windows 7)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

When I attempt to open Eclipse Mars, absolutely nothing happens. I don't get prompted to select my workspace or anything.

I've seen people run into this problem after update from Luna to Mars but I've been using Mars for a while now and this only just started happening today.

I've removed any software and undone any updates that could have potentially caused this to happen but it's still occurring.

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason the eclipse.ini file didn't contain the field that pointed it to where my JDK was. Added it in under the `-vm ` tag and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Kill if there is any existing process of eclipse.exe and javaw.exe from background using task manager and try to run eclipse as administrator.

It could be due to lack of permission.

Comment: I checked the process list. eclipse.exe and javaw.exe weren't in the list. I still tried to run it as an administrator and I'm still getting nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *YOUR_WORKSPACE_PATH*/.metadata/.log file for exceptions. Moreover, I would add the system property `-Dosgi.clean=true` to the eclipse.ini file (this property enforces the cleanup of the OSGi cache).